# Parametrize spring configuration

Tags: java, spring

Assuming you have the following spring configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public SomeBean someBean() {
        SomeBean someBean = new SomeBean();
        someBean.setVar("foobar");
        return someBean;
    }
}
```

Then I can use this configuration in some other class for example by importing it with `@Import(Config.class)`. Now, say you don't want to hardcode the string "foobar" but pass it as a parameter to that configuration. How would I do that? It would be nice to create a custom annotation like `@FooBarConfiguration(var = "foobar")`. Is that possible?

Comment: Does add this value in the properties file is an option for you? You can use @Value to that: `someBean(@Value("${some.variable.from.properties}") String fooBar)`

Comment: @Dherik And without property file? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @Ben answer is the classic and better approach. But if you don't want to use a property file, you can use a `@Bean` for that. Each `@Bean` holds a value that you would like to inject.

Full code example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So49053082Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Bean
    String beanValueFooBar() {
        return "fooBar";
    }

    @Bean
    String beanValueBarFoo() {
        return "barFoo";
    }

    private class SomeBean {

        private String var;

        public void setVar(final String var) {
            this.var = var;
        }
    }


    @Configuration
    public class Config {
        @Bean
        public SomeBean someBean(String beanValueBarFoo) {
            SomeBean someBean = new SomeBean();
            System.out.println(beanValueBarFoo);
            someBean.setVar(beanValueBarFoo);
            return someBean;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So49053082Application.class, args);
        context.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the @Value annotation:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Value("${myParamValue}")
    public String myParam;

    @Bean
    public SomeBean someBean() {
        SomeBean someBean = new SomeBean();
        someBean.setVar(myParam);
        return someBean;
    }
}
```

you'll need to put the parameters into the environment somehow: there are various techniques using the OS environment, runtime parameters or configuration files, as suits your purposes.

Comment: I would prefer having the value directly in the code instead of placing it in some property file. Is that not possible?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the requirement: what is going to determine what value is selected at runtime?